# Laravel, alternative ways of this codes to appear beautiful without changing its meaning

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Is there any alternative ways which are more shorter and beautiful? Currently using the Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
{
    if($value->{'red'} == 1)
    {
        DB::table('furnitures')->insert(
        [
            'chair' => $value->{'Chair Name'},
            'desk' => $value->{'Desk Name'},
            'tv' => $value->{'TV Name'},
            'lamp' => $value->{'Lamp Name'}
            'carpet' => 1,
        ]);
    }

    if($value->{'green'} == 1)
    {
        DB::table('furnitures')->insert(
        [
            'chair' => $value->{'Chair Name'},
            'desk' => $value->{'Desk Name'},
            'tv' => $value->{'TV Name'},
            'lamp' => $value->{'Lamp Name'}
            'carpet' => 2,
        ]);
    }

    if($value->{'blue'} == 1)
    {
        DB::table('furnitures')->insert(
        [
            'chair' => $value->{'Chair Name'},
            'desk' => $value->{'Desk Name'},
            'tv' => $value->{'TV Name'},
            'lamp' => $value->{'Lamp Name'}
            'carpet' => 3,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Notice the 'carpet' changes value according to the colors (red, green, blue). You must be asking "why all conditions are if, why not else if?" Its because i wanted to store all the values with different 'carpet' value althought all the other value is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try something like this :

```
$colors = ['red' => 1, 'green' => 2, 'blue' => 3];
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($colors as $color_name => $color_value) {
        if ($value->{$color_name} == 1) {
            DB::table('furnitures')->insert(
                [
                    'chair'  => $value->{'Chair Name'},
                    'desk'   => $value->{'Desk Name'},
                    'tv'     => $value->{'TV Name'},
                    'lamp'   => $value->{'Lamp Name'},
                    'carpet' => $color_value,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my, that code was too pretty and beautiful! Thank you very much!